# PostgreSQL libpq: PQNumber and column aliases

Tags: sql, c, postgresql, libpq

In a Postgres libpq sql there is a function PQfnumber: Returns the column number associated with the given column name.

Lets say I have a select:

```
select a.*, b.* from a, b where a.id = b.id
```

now if I will call

```
number = PQfnumber(pgresult, "a.id");
```

it will return -1.

Correct way is to call:

```
number = PQfnumber(pgresult, "id");
```

which returns position of a.id. So how would I need to call the function to get column number of b.id?
The only way around it seems to write a different select:

```
select a.id as a_id, a.*, b.id as b_id, b.* from a, b where a.id = b.id

number = PQfnumber(pgresult, "b_id");
```

Any other way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you've found the right way.

Of course, with `a.id = b.id` in an inner join (as in the example code), why would you care which column you were looking at?  Also, there are good reasons *not* to have just an `id` column as the primary key of every table.  Even if a lot of tables have single-column integer keys, if you consistently name columns which hold a primary key to a given table, terser and more efficient syntax like `JOIN ... USING` is available.

Answer (score 0):

If you use construct like this:

> ```
> number = PQfnumber(pgresult, "a.id");
> ```

then you're query should contain a column alias like this:

```sql
SELECT a.id AS "a.id", b.* FROM a, b WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

You do have ambiguity in your code, should you tried such query in the PL/pgSQL language, you would have received the `42702: ambiguous_column` exception.

I see the only way out here — you should give unique aliases for all the ambitious columns of your query. In fact, it is a good practice to give aliases for all columns, I always do so.